# C# NetworkcommsDotNet reset Buffer

Tags: c#, networkcomms.net

actually i have a problem at my client - server communication with tcp and the dll (Networkcomms).
Well all works pretty fine but the problem is the following:
Client sends data a = 123 to the server. The server recive a with 123 and sends a back to the client, a recive a 123 and all is fine. But when the client now sends again data to the server, the server send it back 2 times. Next call 3 times and and and. Well it seems for me if i have to delete the buffer or cache, but i dont know how. I already tried to dispose the connection, but it doesnt affected.

I already read the documentation of Networkcomms, and in their example of a client - server communication is no reset needed, but well as i can see it is needed.

Are there any ideas?

Best regards from Germany

EDIT:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NetworkComms.AppendGlobalIncomingPacketHandler<string>("Message", PrintIncommingMessage);
        Connection.StartListening(ConnectionType.TCP, new System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 666));
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    private static void PrintIncommingMessage(PacketHeader header,Connection connection,string message)
    {
        string data = message;
        string[] datasplit = data.Split(new char[] { '/' });
        if(datasplit[0] == "IstReady")
        {
            if (ReadyName == null)
            {
                conn2 = connection;
                ReadyName = datasplit[1];
                Console.WriteLine(ReadyName + " ist ready!\n");
            }
            else
            {
                connection.SendObject("Message","Start");
                conn2.SendObject("Message","Start");
                ReadyName = null;
            }
        }

        if (datasplit[0] == "SetUserPosition")
        {
            if(User1 == null||User1 == datasplit[1])
            {
                User1 = datasplit[1];
                User1Y = datasplit[2];
            }
            else
            {
                User2 = datasplit[1];
                User2Y = datasplit[2];
            }
        }

        if (datasplit[0] == "GetUserPosition")
        {
            if(User1 == datasplit[1])
            {
                connection.SendObject("Message","GotUserY/"+User1Y);
            }
            else if(User2 == datasplit[1])
            {
                connection.SendObject("Message", "GotUserY/"+User2Y);
            }
        }
    }
```

**ANSWER:**
I forgot that i called multiple times ,,NetworkComms.AppendGlobalIncomingPacketHandler("Message", PrintIncommingMessage);" this function at my client-site. Thats why i got every time more and more results, because i added multiple handlers. Well an really easy problem, but i totally overread my timer which added the handler.

Comment: Thanks for your question. Are you able to include code samples in your question? If I had to guess something on your 'server' end is duplicating the response data.

Comment: i added the code, thanks.

Comment: So the receiving buffer get's cleared when the incoming data is passed to the PacketHandler and I can't see any problems on the server side. Do you have the client code?

Comment: That sounds most likely like an event gets registered on each call. The code above shows no obvious problem, though I dont know the specific library well.

Comment: Hey, so yeah Andres was totally right, i forgot that i have a little line of code which i add every timer tick, and there was included appendincomingpacket....

That was the reason, thank you a lot for your help guys.

And by the way @MarcF thank you for such a good network-communication help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot that i called multiple times ,,NetworkComms.AppendGlobalIncomingPacketHandler("Message", PrintIncommingMessage);" this function at my client-site. Thats why i got every time more and more results, because i added multiple handlers. Well an really easy problem, but i totally overread my timer which added the handler.